# c++ call object method using pointer

Tags: c++, dlopen, dlsym

I created a shared lib, in which I defined a class Foo. In class Foo, there is a function named sayHi(). My question is once I created a Foo object foo, how can I call sayHi() of it. I put my code here.

mylib.h

```
#ifndef FUNTEST_MYLIB_H
#define FUNTEST_MYLIB_H


class Foo {
public:
    int id = 0;
    void sayHi();
};


#endif //FUNTEST_MYLIB_H
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mylib.h"

using namespace std;

void Foo::sayHi()
{
    cout << "Implemented by lib" << endl;
    cout << "id is: " << id << endl;
}

Foo* create()
{
    return new Foo();
}
```

then I use the following commands compile the shared lib:

```
g++ -c -std=gnu++11 -fPIC mylib.cpp
g++ -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so mylib.o
```

At the client side, I write two files:

mylib2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mylib.h"

using namespace std;

void Foo::sayHi() {
    cout << "Implemented by caller" << endl;
    cout << "id is: " << id << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "mylib.h"

using namespace std;

Foo* (*create)();
void (*sayHi)();
int main() {
    void* lib = dlopen("./mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    create = (Foo* (*)())dlsym(lib, "_Z6createv");
    sayHi = (void (*)())dlsym(lib, "_ZN3Foo5sayHiEv");

    Foo* foo = create();

    sayHi();
    foo->sayHi();

    foo->id = 100;
    cout << "Set id to " << foo->id << endl;

    /*
     *
     * how can I make the follow statement 'sayHi();'
     * output the following content:
     * Implemented by lib
     * id is: 100
     */
    sayHi(); // line 29, FIXME
    foo->sayHi();

    return 0;
}
```

compile the client with following command:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp mylib.h mylib2.cpp -ldl
```

finally run the client:
./a.out

the output is:

```
Implemented by lib
id is: 0
Implemented by caller
id is: 0
Set id to 100
Implemented by lib
id is: -1407102376 // FIXME
Implemented by caller
id is: 100
```

how can I make the statement 'sayHi();' at line 29 output the following content:

```
Implemented by lib 
id is: 100
```

I know if i call the sayHi() function directly, without the foo object, the output will be wrong. But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the `sayHi` global variable in main.cpp is wrong.  You're declaring it as a function pointer.  However, since it points to a member function, it needs to be a member function pointer.

```
void (Foo::*sayHi)();
```

Then when you call it you need a `Foo` object:

```
(foo->*sayHi)();
```

Alternatively, if you make the `sayHi` method `virtual`, you shouldn't need to load the symbol for it at all, since that will be effectively handled by the vtable.

Comment: So great of you, thank you for you quick reply. Another question is how can I get the function pointer? The following statement is wrong:

 sayHi = (void (Foo::*)())dlsym(lib, "_ZN3Foo5sayHiEv");

Comment: I have change sayHi() to virtual, it works fine. But what if I want to reference it using member pointer? I mean use dlsym to get the method symbol. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's solved:     reinterpret_cast<void*&> (sayHi) = dlsym(lib, "_ZN3Foo5sayHiEv");

Comment: I've got another question. If I implement the sayHi() in mylib.h directory without declaration statement: void sayHi(); I cannot use dlsym get the symbol, how can I solve it? thank you.